# Extract rows from a range that meet criteria in another column of the same df

Tags: r

I have the following df

```
df <- data.frame(value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), win=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5))

> df
   value win
1      1   1
2      2   1
3      3   1
4      4   2
5      5   2
6      6   3
7      7   4
8      8   4
9      9   5
10    10   5
```

And I wanted to keep only the rows where the variable win is in more that 3 rows. So if I look into

```
> table(df$win)

1 2 3 4 5 
3 2 1 2 2
```

I know that I will only want to keep the rows where win=1. But how do I do that for a big data frame ?

I was thinking of having a vector which would give me the unique values of df$win

```
xx <- unique(df$win)

> xx
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

And somehow make a loop where it would count which rows does df$win == xx and then extract only those rows but I wasn't able to make it come true so if any of you could help me I would be very thankfull !

Edit

Expected output [only for this example tho so doing subset(df, win =="1") is not useful as I don't know which "win" will be in more than 3 rows]

```
    > new_df
     value win
1      1   1
2      2   1
3      3   1
```

Comment: Whats the expected output?

Comment: maybe `df |> dplyr::group_by(win) |> dplyr::filter(n() >=3)`

Comment: @TomHoel I updated with the expected output given the follow example

@AndS. It did work. I only had to add an extra line after your input with 
`new_df1 <- as.data.frame(new_df)`

I'm new to this so I do I "accept" your comment here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a big dataset, use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, if(.N>=3) .SD, win]
```

Output:

```
   win value
1:   1     1
2:   1     2
3:   1     3
```